# Jquery help with toggle menu

Tags: jquery

I created a button, what i want to do is when i hover it, a menu toggle out with animation. But when I moved the cursor over the menu, the menu toggle back, because it now read that the cursor not  hover on the button anymore.  I try to use "e.preventDefault();", it stop the menu toggle back in, but all the animation seem to canceled out.

Here is the code:

```
$("#logoSmall").hover(function(){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $("#safety_nav").toggle(function(){


            $(this).animate({top: '40px', opacity:'1'}, function(){
                $(this).hover(function(){
                        //I don't know what to put here.
                    });
            });
        });

    });
```

Please help! What am i missing? What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Where does the menu show up on the page? Do you have HTML or (better yet) a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can look at?

Comment: sorry here ... please take a look jsfiddle.net/rRbWz/11

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery's API documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), toggle cannot take a function as it's first parameter. You'll have to specify a duration first:

```
$("#safety_nav").toggle(500, function(){...
```

Comment: so you mean by adding the duration, it will solve the problem?

Comment: @minhtu Since you haven't shown us any of your HTML, I cannot comment on that. But, hey, why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's homework, I'm inclined to give advice rather than code :-)

It's not a code issue as much as planning - the button is the trigger of the menu pop up, but you'll want to test for the mouse being over the menu div OR the button. The behavior you're looking for is more of a UI strategy than a single answer.

One way you can approach it is to bind the button to hover on, but make the test for re-hiding the div be the mouse NEITHER on the button or #safety_nav.

Additionally you may wish to add a behavior where either any menu activating de-activates the others, and the user clicking outside any menu div hides all of them (as fallback behaviors in case the browser is wonky at reporting mouse over/out conditions)

Good luck!

Comment: I'm assuming you figured it out, but if not, take a look at the bottom demo on this page: [link]http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Sorry, I meant to send you to mouse leave - the demo is the same (but it explains why you should use mouse leave not mouse out) : http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

See http://jsfiddle.net/hanleybrand/rRbWz/30/ (an edit of your fiddle)

Comment: also, I noticed that the mouse enter/leave behaviors are a bit wonky inside of jsfiddle, so you may wish to look at http://jsfiddle.net/hanleybrand/rRbWz/30/show/ to get a better sense - it's not perfect, but it's getting towards where you need to go